# I can't install new python packages, or upgrade pip and setuptools

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I'm new to both python and linux. I have python 3.4 on a Uberstudent linux distribution(based on Ubuntu 14.04).

I'm trying to get a progress bar for scripts in python. So I run

`pip install progressbar`

in the command line. Then I get the error

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

After searching for a while I find that this is because pip, setuptools and wheel are not up to date. So I run

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

and I get the output

```
Downloading/unpacking pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/b6/ac/7015eb97dc749283ffdec1c3a88ddb8ae03b8fad0f0e611408f196358da3/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=297dbd16ef53bcef0447d245815f5144
  Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB): 1.3MB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking setuptools from https://pypi.python.org/packages/43/41/033a273f9a25cb63050a390ee8397acbc7eae2159195d85f06f17e7be45a/setuptools-38.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=908b8b5e50bf429e520b2b5fa1b350e5
  Downloading setuptools-38.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (489kB): 489kB downloaded
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools
  Found existing installation: pip 1.5.4
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, owned by OS
  Can't roll back pip; was not uninstalled
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 523, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pip_build_martin/pip/pip-9.0.1.dist-info/WHEEL' -> '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.dist-info/WHEEL'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 672, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 206, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 200, in clobber
    shutil.move(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 535, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 245, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 109, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.dist-info/WHEEL'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/martin/.pip/pip.log
```

After some further digging I find that i should try to uninstall it and install it again. But this gives the same permission denied error. And using get-pip.py also gives the same error.

I have no idea what any of this means or why I don't have permission to upgrade pip.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), maybe already installed, so skip the first 2 lines :

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
$ mkdir test_virtualenv
$ cd test_virtualenv
$ virtualenv .
$ bin/pip install foobar
```

Comment: what does virtualenv do? from the name it sounds like a virtual environment, if so, what does that mean? do i have to do something before i want to use the virtual environtment in python?

Comment: There a link referenced to `virtualenv`, maybe can you take a bit of your own time to read it ? Or at least search it on duckduckgo or any search engine ? If you have `virtualenv`, then all can be run as _simple user_ (like the `$` means)